# pg-go RunInTransaction not rolling back the transaction

Tags: postgresql, go, testify

I'm trying to rollback a transaction on my unit tests, between scenarios, to keep the database empty and do not make my tests dirty. So, I'm trying:

```
for _, test := range tests {
   db := connect()
   _ = db.RunInTransaction(func() error {
      t.Run(test.name, func(t *testing.T) {
         for _, r := range test.objToAdd {
            err := db.PutObj(&r)
            require.NoError(t, err)
         }
         objReturned, err := db.GetObjsWithFieldEqualsXPTO()
         require.NoError(t, err)
         require.Equal(t, test.queryResultSize, len(objReturned))
      })
      return fmt.Errorf("returning error to clean up the database rolling back the transaction")
   })
}
```

I was expecting to rollback the transaction on the end of the scenario, so the next for step will have an empty database, but when I run, the data is never been rolling back.

I believe I'm trying to do what the doc suggested: https://pg.uptrace.dev/faq/#how-to-test-mock-database, am I right?

More info: I notice that my interface is implementing a layer over RunInTransaction as:

```
func (gs *DB) RunInTransaction(fn func() error) error {
    f := func(*pg.Tx) error { return fn() }
    return gs.pgDB.RunInTransaction(f)
}
```

IDK what is the problem yet, but I really guess that is something related to that (because the TX is encapsulated just inside the RunInTransaction implementation.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you might find [this helpful](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-txdb)--it basically does all the transactions for you.

Comment: As my first try I would check the returned value of db.RunInTransaction, maybe the rollback fails somewhere.

Comment: Debugging, the code execute as expected, the rollback line pass, the error is returned (even when I added a require.Error to confirm, it pass.... but even so, the database continues to commit the values after each scenario.

Comment: I notice that my runInTransaction was been implemented and encapsulating the TX. Added the code to the question, if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[go-pg](https://github.com/go-pg/pg) uses connection pooling (in common with most go database packages). This means that when you call a database function (e.g. [`db.Exec`](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/v9.2.0/base.go#L199)) it will grab a connection from the pool (establishing a new one if needed), run the command and return the connection to the pool.

When running a transaction you need to run [`BEGIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-begin.html), whatever updates etc you require, followed by [`COMMIT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-commit.html)/[`ROLLBACK`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-rollback.html), on a single connection dedicated to the transaction (any commands sent on other connections are not part of the transaction). This is why [Begin()](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/v9.2.0/tx.go#L47) (and effectively `RunInTransaction`) provide you with a [`pg.Tx`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-pg/pg/v9@v9.2.0#Tx); use this to run commands within the transaction.

[example_test.go](https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/v9.2.0/example_test.go#L179) provides an example covering the usage of [`RunInTransaction`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-pg/pg/v9@v9.2.0#Conn.RunInTransaction):

```
incrInTx := func(db *pg.DB) error {
        // Transaction is automatically rollbacked on error.
        return db.RunInTransaction(func(tx *pg.Tx) error {
            var counter int
            _, err := tx.QueryOne(
                pg.Scan(&counter), `SELECT counter FROM tx_test FOR UPDATE`)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            counter++

            _, err = tx.Exec(`UPDATE tx_test SET counter = ?`, counter)
            return err
        })
    }
```

You will note that this only uses the `pg.DB` when calling `RunInTransaction`; all database operations use the transaction `tx` (a [pg.Tx](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-pg/pg/v9@v9.2.0#Tx)). `tx.QueryOne` will be run within the transaction; if you ran `db.QueryOne` then that would be run outside of the transaction.

So [`RunInTransaction`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-pg/pg/v9@v9.2.0#Conn.RunInTransaction) begins a transaction and passes the relevant [Tx](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-pg/pg/v9@v9.2.0#Tx) in as a parameter to the function you provide. You wrap this with:

```golang
func (gs *DB) RunInTransaction(fn func() error) error {
    f := func(*pg.Tx) error { return fn() }
    return gs.pgDB.RunInTransaction(f)
}
```

This effectively ignores the `pg.Tx` and you then run commands using other connections (e.g. `err := db.PutObj(&r)`) (i.e. outside of the transaction). To fix this you need to use the transaction (e.g. `err := tx.PutObj(&r)`).